# Proof on a statement

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to prove this question. The integral of a regulated function does not depend on the approximating sequence of step functions. Is it possible to give a guided description to help me understand how to solve this please.

Comment: How is integral of a regulated function defined ?

Comment: If f is a regulated function on $[a,b]$, we define the regulated integral by \\ $\int_{a,b}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to\inf} \int_{a,b}f_n(x)\,dx$
where ${f_n}$ is any sequence of step functions converging uniformly to f.

Comment: @Mambo, forgot to tag you to the comment

Comment: Hint: Set of all step functions is dense in the set of all regulated functions.

Comment: I gathered that already but I don't know how that is relevant?